# mod_rewrite not working on Magento installation

Tags: .htaccess, url, magento, mod-rewrite

I've recently installed magento to a new server. The domain name has not been pointed to the server yet because I still need to design the site, so for now I'm using an IP address.

Example:
11.222.3.44/~clientname/

I'm trying to turn on magento's url rewrites to remove "index.php" after "/~clientname/" on every page, however when ever I turn rewrites on the site stops working and I get a 404. Would this be due to the IP address and the trailing client name I'm using? If so, how can this be corrected?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Check if the RewriteEngine is On, RewriteBase is ok in the .htaccess. In your case it should be RewriteBase /~clientname/

And of course check that the mod_rewrite is installed and enabled but I think it's already done.

Comment: You're welcome. Do not forget to vote and validate the response :)